# How to see if a list of strings is contained (not equal) within another list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings that are set up in a date format (the date is text so I will keep it that way).

I need to check it against another list of strings where the list of strings that are date format type could be anywhere in those list of strings.

I've tried all kinds of .Any() with .Contains(), but .Contains forces you to take a string and I need to look at the entire string because it will not be equal.

```
            var innerTextList = getMainData.Select(s => s.InnerText).ToList();
            bool hasMatch = innerTextList.Contains(dateList.Select(s => s)).Any();
```

Example:

List of strings (date text format) -DateTextList

"Thu, Mar 28"

"Fri, Mar 29"

"Sat, Mar 30"

---

List of Strings - RecordTextList

"Thu, Mar 28vs Pittsburgh W5-3 1-0Duke 1-0Taillon 0-1Hernandez 144,049"

"Sun, Mar 31vs Pittsburgh 1:10 PM Roark Musgrove Tickets as low as $14"

"Tue, Mar 26vs Pittsburgh 1:10 PM Roark Musgrove Tickets as low as $14"

So if any of the DateTextList records is contained in the list of records of RecordTextList, I want to return TRUE.

Comment: [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool hasMatch = DateTextList.Any(x => RecordTextList.Any(y => y.Contains(x)));
```

Comment: YES!  This is exactly what I need. It has to be case sensitive though!  Thank you Guilherme!

Comment: This answer *is* case-sensitive. If you meant case **in**sensitive, then you can use `IndexOf`, for example:  `bool hasMatch = DateTextList.Any(date => RecordTextList.Any(record => record.IndexOf(date, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1));`